# How to use Application Verifier in the Windows Phone Developer Power Tools?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

[Test and troubleshoot apps with the Windows Phone Developer Power Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn629255.aspx)

[image]

I know how to use the Performance Monitor and Performance Recorder
**but I can't fully understand the application verifier**.
I just follow the guide,**try to check some options and hit the "Apply"**, but nothing special happens.

Could you tell me the correct way to use the application verifier?

Comment: Got the same question. Anybody?

Comment: Looks like the MS has listened to our prayers and has put that article on the web: https://sysdev.microsoft.com/en-US/Hardware/OEM/docs/Debugging/Application_Verifier_on_Windows_Phone